# How to display the search box beside the header column

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application i need to display the search box beside the header column that is beside EmpName but it displays the search box below the employee name.How can i place the search box beside the header of the gridview.The screen shot that  had attached shows i am getting the search box below the header EmpName but i should get beside EmpName.How can i do this

```
<style type="text/css">
        .Gridview {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksearch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.search_textbox').each(function (i) {
                $(this).quicksearch("[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                    'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                        return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="true">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeader="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmpId" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" UseAccessibleHeader ="true">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle Width="80px" />
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="EmpName" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="salary" HeaderText="Salary" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="150" />

                                <%--                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" CancelText="" DeleteText="" EditText='<%#Eval("notes").ToString()=="" ? "add" : "edit" %>' UpdateText='<%# Eval("notes")%>' />--%>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text='<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("notes").ToString()))  ? "Add":"Edit"%>' ID="btnAdd" />
                                        <asp:Button CommandName="Update" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("notes").ToString()))  ? "Save":"Update"%>' ID="btnUpdate" />
                                        <%-- <asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ID="btnCancel" />--%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>

        </div>

 private SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=EHSD208;Database=Training;User Id=sa;Password=Access#123");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                gvbind();
            }
        }
        protected void gvbind()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from EmpDet", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            gvbind();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            gvbind();
            Button addButton = (Button)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("btnAdd");
            addButton.Visible = false;
            Button updateButton = (Button)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("btnUpdate");
            updateButton.Visible = true;

            //Button cancelButton = (Button)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("btnCancel");
            //cancelButton.Visible = true;
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            int EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            TextBox textc1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update EmpDet set notes='" + textc1.Text + "'where EmpId='" + EmpId + "'", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            gvbind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            //gvbind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[3].Text))
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            //for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            //{
                TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
                txtSearch.Attributes["Search Box"] = GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText;
                txtSearch.CssClass = "search_textbox";
                cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
                row.Controls.Add(cell);
            //}
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
        }
    }
```

Above is my complete code and the code that is related to search box is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksearch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.search_textbox').each(function (i) {
                $(this).quicksearch("[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                    'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                        return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    }
                });

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeader="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmpId" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" UseAccessibleHeader ="true">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle Width="80px" />
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="EmpName" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="salary" HeaderText="Salary" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="150" />

                                <%--                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" CancelText="" DeleteText="" EditText='<%#Eval("notes").ToString()=="" ? "add" : "edit" %>' UpdateText='<%# Eval("notes")%>' />--%>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text='<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("notes").ToString()))  ? "Add":"Edit"%>' ID="btnAdd" />
                                        <asp:Button CommandName="Update" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("notes").ToString()))  ? "Save":"Update"%>' ID="btnUpdate" />
                                        <%-- <asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ID="btnCancel" />--%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
            });
        });
    </script>
  protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            //for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            //{
                TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
                txtSearch.Attributes["Search Box"] = GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText;
                txtSearch.CssClass = "search_textbox";
                cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
                row.Controls.Add(cell);
            //}
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a jsfiddle of this that doesn't have all the .net tags?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is a site that lets you post html, css, and javascript to allow anyone to see how it would render. It's hard to read through all the source code without being able to see the rendered HTML.

Comment: You can find the "rendered HTML" using `view-source:`. Then copy/paste HTML/CSS/JS in the relevant sections of [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/). Type this in your browser's adress bar : view-source:localhost:61290/Webform2.aspx